# unable to run manage.py

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am a student (using Ubuntu 18.04) learning django and mysql.
I have a problem when I try to run manage.py.
When I type: **'python manage.py runserver'**, then I get an error message at the end saying
**django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")**.
Is there any a solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It's mysql related problem

Comment: looks like you are using a wrong db account.

Comment: Check the database configuration in your `settings.py`.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Thanks for the reply. I typed 'SELECT DISTINCT user FROM mysql.user' to check username and gave me a list of users including 'root'. And on settings.py, I have databases info for 'USER' named as 'root'. Doesn't this mean i have a correct username?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I was just trying to find my password for the root. But I could not find a way to check it, so i just changed the password for root by typing 'UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root'; What can i do next?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal i just replaced my password in settings.py and tried it again. However, it gives me a new error message saying 'django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1039, "Unknown database 'imgs'"). imgs is the name of the database in settings.py.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks so much. I spent this whole night trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out the MySQL password for user `root`.
2. Put it in settings.py

   ```
   ...
   'NAME': 'imgs',
   'USER': 'root',
   'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
   ...
   ```
3. Create a database in MySQL with the same name as specified in settings.

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE imgs
   ```
4. Run `python manage.py runserver`